Keyboard problem on new Asus Vivobook Pro 15 N6506MV in Ubuntu 24.04
Keyboard on laptop is not working at all only on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop, on Windows there is no problem with keyboard.
description: Notebook
product: ASUS Vivobook Pro 15 N6506MV_N6506MV
vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
version: 1.0
serial: S2N0CV0*****
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.6.0 dmi-3.6.0 smp vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ASUS Vivobook Pro 15 uuid=548f915e-7a11-f640-bc42-3a208d28652a

  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: N6506MV
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: S205N*******
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends International, LLC.
          physical id: 0
          version: N6506MV.304
          date: 01/30/2024
          size: 64KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd acpi biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 12
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 24GiB
        *-
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 9 185H
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 26
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.170.4
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2001MHz
          capacity: 4800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect user_shstk avx_vnni dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req hfi vnmi umip pku ospke waitpkg gfni vaes vpclmulqdq tme rdpid bus_lock_detect movdiri movdir64b fsrm md_clear serialize pconfig arch_lbr ibt flush_l1d arch_capabilities intel_ppin cpufreq
          configuration: cores=16 enabledcores=16 microcode=28 threads=22
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 04
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=igen6_edac
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:88000000-890fffff ioport:4000000000(size=8623489024)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=2880x1620 visual=truecolor xres=2880 yres=1620
                resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:420-41f irq:234 memory:88000000-88ffffff memory:4000000000-41ffffffff memory:4200000000-4201ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:89000000-8907ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: NVIDIA Corporation
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                logical name: card0
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:89080000-89083fff
              *-input:0
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input25
                   logical name: /dev/input/event8
              *-input:1
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7
                   physical id: 1
                   logical name: input26
                   logical name: /dev/input/event9
              *-input:2
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: input27
                   logical name: /dev/input/event10
              *-input:3
                   product: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9
                   physical id: 3
                   logical name: input28
                   logical name: /dev/input/event11
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P [Intel Arc Graphics]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 08
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=2880,1620
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f iomemory:420-41f irq:233 memory:4a20000000-4a20ffffff memory:4210000000-421fffffff memory:c0000-dffff memory:4202000000-4208ffffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal_pci latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:16 memory:4a30280000-4a3029ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:89500000-895fffff
         
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 6.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.2
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:89400000-894fffff
           *-nvme
                description: NVMe device
                product: WD PC SN560 SDDPNQE-1T00-1102
                vendor: Sandisk Corp
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: /dev/nvme1
                version: 74114000
                serial: 2338CX404252
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: nvme pm msi msix pciexpress nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0 nqn=nqn.2018-01.com.wdc:guid:E8238FA6BF53-0001-001B444A483A6EB0 state=live
                resources: irq:16 memory:89400000-89403fff
              
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:82000000-87ffffff ioport:4220000000(size=34359738368)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f memory:4a302e4000-4a302e4fff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_vsec latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:0 memory:4a30240000-4a3027ffff
        *-generic:3
             description: Processing accelerators
             product: Meteor Lake NPU
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_vpu latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f iomemory:4a0-49f irq:211 memory:4a28000000-4a2fffffff memory:4a302e3000-4a302e3fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:157 memory:4a302c0000-4a302cffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.2
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix usb4_host_interface bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f iomemory:4a0-49f irq:16 memory:4a30200000-4a3023ffff memory:4a302e2000-4a302e2fff
        *-communication:0
             description: Serial controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 8250 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_ish_ipc latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:128 memory:4a302b0000-4a302bffff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:145 memory:4a302a0000-4a302affff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB Receiver
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 29.01
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-input:0
                      product: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023
                      physical id: 0
                      logical name: input36
                      logical name: /dev/input/event5
                      logical name: input36::capslock
                      logical name: input36::compose
                      logical name: input36::kana
                      logical name: input36::numlock
                      logical name: input36::scrolllock
                      capabilities: usb
                 *-input:1
                      product: Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4022
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: input37
                      logical name: /dev/input/event6
                      logical name: /dev/input/mouse2
                      capabilities: usb
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: ASUS 5M WebCam
                   vendor: Shinetech
                   physical id: 9
                   bus info: usb@1:9
                   version: 0.02
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: AX211 Bluetooth
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.8.0-31-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 6.08
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                            configuration: created=2024-04-13 23:19:31 filesystem=ext4 label=writable lastmountpoint=/root/var/crash modified=2024-04-30 10:35:57 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2024-04-30 10:35:57 state=mounted
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f iomemory:4a0-49f memory:4a302d8000-4a302dbfff memory:4a302e1000-4a302e1fff
        *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlo1
             version: 20
             serial: e8:c8:29:25:3e:60
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 ma-b0-gf-a0-86.uc ip=192.168.0.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:18 memory:4a302d4000-4a302d7fff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:4209000000-4209000fff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:33 memory:4209001000-4209001fff
        *-communication:1
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:212 memory:4a302de000-4a302defff
        *-serial:2
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:4209002000-4209002fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:126 memory:89300000-893fffff
           *-generic
                description: MMC Host
                product: GL9755 SD Host Controller
                vendor: Genesys Logic, Inc
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
                logical name: mmc0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:153 memory:89300000-89300fff
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:127 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:89200000-892fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:2f:00.0
                logical name: enp47s0
                version: 15
                serial: 10:7c:61:bd:d2:f4
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:89204000-89204fff memory:89200000-89203fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0303
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             logical name: card1
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D2
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D31p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D4p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D5p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D6c
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl latency=32
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f iomemory:4a0-49f irq:235 memory:4a302d0000-4a302d3fff memory:4a30000000-4a301fffff
        *-serial:3
             description: SMBus
             product: Meteor Lake-P SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: iomemory:4a0-49f irq:18 memory:4a302dc000-4a302dc0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-serial:4
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Meteor Lake-P SPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=intel-spi latency=0
             resources: irq:0 memory:80800000-80800fff
  *-input:0
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 1
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       logical name: input2::capslock
       logical name: input2::numlock
       logical name: input2::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:3
       product: Asus WMI hotkeys
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input24
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:4
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input29
       logical name: /dev/input/event12
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input30
       logical name: /dev/input/event13
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:6
       product: sof-hda-dsp Headset Mic
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input31
       logical name: /dev/input/event14
  *-input:7
       product: sof-hda-dsp Headphone
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input32
       logical name: /dev/input/event15
  *-input:8
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input33
       logical name: /dev/input/event16
  *-input:9
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
       physical id: a
       logical name: input34
       logical name: /dev/input/event17
  *-input:10
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
       physical id: b
       logical name: input35
       logical name: /dev/input/event18
  *-input:11
       product: ASUP1A04:00 093A:300B Mouse
       physical id: c
       logical name: input5
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i2c
  *-input:12
       product: ASUP1A04:00 093A:300B Touchpad
       physical id: d
       logical name: input6
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i2c


6.8.0-31-generic
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"

Keyboard on laptop is not working at all only on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop, on Windows there is no problem with keyboard.

Found bug on  https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218745, now compiling kernel

It is a bug in kernel 6.8 and older. It has been solved in kernel 6.9 (and I guess 6.10 as well) for my Asus Vivobook Pro 15 N6506M. You can easily update the kernel via mainline
